# Ms Bot Builder : How to create a hierarchical library structure?

Tags: botframework

Let's say I create a library `shop` and add to my bot :

**dialogs/shop.js**

```
 var lib = new builder.Library('shop');
    lib.dialog('car', function(session){})

    module.exports.createLibrary = function () {
        return lib.clone();
    };
```

**bot/index.js**

```
bot.library(require('./dialogs/shop').createLibrary());
```

So I can trigger the `car` dialog through `session.beginDialog('shop:car')`.

I'm looking to create a library for each category of items to shop so car comes within `vehicle` library and I get to call the `car` dialog through `session.beginDialog('shop:vehicle:car')`

I tried doing this :

```
var lib = new builder.Library('shop');
var lib_vehicle = new builder.Library('vehicle');

lib_vehicle.dialog('car', function(session){})

lib.library(lib_vehicle.clone());

module.exports.createLibrary = function () {
    return lib.clone();
};

bot.library(require('./dialogs/shop').createLibrary());
```

But this triggers `car` dialog through `session.beginDialog('vehicle:car')` instead of `session.beginDialog('shop:vehicle:car')`

How do I achieve a hierarchical relationship between libraries?

Thanks

Comment: Did the logger send you any messages when attempting to access through id `'shop:vehicle:car'`? I'm curious to what it said; if it threw some errors or not.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code, the SDK isn't set to handle hierarchical structures in this situation you described.

When dealing with `'vehicle:car'`, it generates an array and takes the library name and the dialog id. The session method `findDialog()` (called inside of `beginDialog`) [is hardcoded to only accept one id](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/lib/Session.js#L704), so `'car'`, and everything works fine. For `'shop:vehicle:car'`, `'car'` is essentially left in the dust, and your chatbot goes to look for a dialog with an id of `'vehicle'` in the library `'shop'`.

**Edit:** If you think it's a feature worth exploring, file a [[Feature Request] issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues) in the BotBuilder repo so a discussion can ensue.